# Parsing Cisco router configuration blocks

Tags: java, parsing, cisco

I am trying to parse cisco configuration. It has indented structure like below. There are lots of blocks like this. Some blocks can be longer. `!` sign means end of the indent above. How can i parse blocks and sub blocks under blocks?

- Ex1 :

  ```
  XXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                \          
    XXXXXXXXXXXX    \              |         
      XXXXXX         | sub-block   | block
      XXXXXX         |             |         
    !               /              |         
  !                               /        
  XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXX
  ```
- Ex2 :

  ```
  XXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX               \       
      XXXXXXXXXXXX  \             |      
          XXXXXX     | sub-block  | block
          XXXXXX     |            |      
      !             /             |      
      XXXXXXXXXXXX  \             |       
          XXXXXX     | sub-block  |
      !             /             |
  !                              /
  XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXX
  ```
- Ex3 - The Real Cisco Config :

  ```
  vrf myvrfvir
    address-family ipv4 broadcast
      import route
        10:10
      !
      export route
        20:20
      !
    !
  !
  interface Eth6/3/9/4.10
    description vlan10
    mtu 1500
    dot1q vlan 10
  !
  .
  .
  .
  ```

  There are 4 blocks:

  - First block name is `vrf myvrfvir`,
  - second block name is `interface GigabitEth0/3/5/3.10`,
  - 3rd (sub)block is `import route`,
  - 4th (sub)block is `export route`.

  So i want to be able to get all blocks and store them in hash, list, text or ...

  So i want to reach each block with its block and upper block name when i need.

Comment: I have no idea about what was going through your mind when you posted this

Comment: Following your explanation (that I have refactored a bit for clarity), `address-family ipv4 broadcast` should be also a block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to store block data in a map:

```
class Block {
    private Map<String, String> data;
    private Block parent;
    private List<Block> children;
}
```

Also, you could create another data structure that suits your needs / solves the task you have at hand.

Then, just read a file line by line, detect if you need a new block by tracking number of indents that you have, and populate the data structure above.

Quick and dirty sample (disclaimer: I didn't run this code, that's just to get you started, you should add validations, split it into multiple functions etc. so that it's clean, correct, and nice to read):

```
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        Block block = new Block();
        String line, previousIndents = "";
        while (null != (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(\\s+)").matcher(line);
            if (m.find()) {
                String indents = m.group(1);
                if (previousIndents.equals(indents)) {
                     // update current block
                } else if (indents.length() > previousIndents.length()) {
                     // start a new block
                     Block newBlock = new Block();
                     newBlock.setParent(block);
                     block.getChildren().add(newBlock);

                     block = newBlock;
                } else {
                     // current block finished, return to parent
                     block = block.getParent();
                }

                previousIndents = indents;
            }
        } 
    }
    catch (IOException ioEx) {
        throw new ParseException(ioEx);
    }
```